# Copying Multipart file with attributes - how to get correct creation time

Tags: java, file, spring-boot

I am working on file uploader, that is generates metadata from files and sends them to metadata database.

Problem is, that uploading them with original creation time seems impossible. I started with this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ and most of other that I found online, are very similar. There is html form that runs on server, that is used to upload files. From html form you get `MultipartFile` and uploading looks like this:

```
Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(filename),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Problem is `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` replaces existing creation time. `StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES` is supported only for `Files.copy(Path source, Path target)`. All the other options of copying `MultipartFile` that I found replace creation time too.

To find out creation time I am using this:

```
BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class); 
LocalDateTime ct = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(attributes.creationTime().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Is there a way to upload file with original properties?

Thanks for every constructive answer - even using other framework than spring-boot.

Comment: edited title to be more accurate

Comment: edited one more time